# A question about a hierarchy of metric spaces arising from an operation defined by Hausdorff.

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Given any metric space M, Hausdorff defined a new metric space h(M) whose "points" are the non-empty
closed and bounded subsets of M. The hierarchy emerges from the following iteration process. Let
H(0,M)=M and for each non-negative integer n, let H(n+1,M)=h(H(n,M)). If M is (for example) a finite
dimensional Euclidean space or Hilbert space, does this process ever reach a fixed point-in the sense
that there exists a non-negative integer k for which the spaces H(k,M) and H(k+1,M) are homeomorphic
(or even isometric)? If there is no fixed point in the case of some particular metric space M, is it
possible to continue this iteration process into the transfinite?

Comment: Assume you start with Euclidean space.
The maximal number of points on distance $>\varepsilon$ in the unit ball of $H(n,M)$ grows with $n$.
So you will not reach the roof in finite number of steps. 

Comment: I assume Hausdorff used what is now known as the Hausdorff metric on sets to get metrics on the derived spaces?


Comment: If the discrete metric is used and you start with a space containing an infinite number of points, you get a transfinite sequence that never converges to a fixed point (since the power set has a higher cardinality than the original set and closed bounded sets are all subsets of the space when the metric is discrete). 

Comment: @Kevin, usually $h(M)$ is defined as set of all compact subsets. In this case $M=h(M)$ for countable discrete metric space $M$. 

Comment: @Anton, Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: This question is a bit confusing. It seems obvious that this process continues transfinitely since if we canonically embed H(n,M) into H(n+1,M) at successor stages and take the direct limit at limit ordinals, then we would get always add points each step of this transfinite process. i.e. The transfinite process does not end. Also, this question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/111401/is-the-hyperspace-of-the-hilbert-cube-homeomorphic-to-the-hilbert-cube seems to give an answer for compact Peano continua since the finitary process terminates with the Hilbert cube.

Comment: These comments are very interesting and I am trying to understand
how they affect the possible answers to my questions. If M is a finite-dimensional Euclidean space, are you saying that a maximal
set of points in the closed unit ball of H(n,M) such that no pair
of these points are at a distance apart less than some preassigned
positive number e, has a cardinal number that grows with n? And how
does one cannonically embed H(n,M) into H(n+1,M)?

Comment: It is true that for each non-negative integer n, the collection of
all singletons of "points" of H(n,M) is a subspace of H(n+1,M) that
is isometric to H(n,M). But if one attempts to use this fact to
extend the hierarchy into the transfinite, and if w denotes the
smallest infinite ordinal number, exactly how does one define the
collection of points of the metric space H(w,M)-and exacly how does
one define the metric for this space. Unfortunately, the set of 
relevant notions of category theory such as "direct limits" that I
know anything about, has measure zero.
